# How to give directory name and write to text file using java in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, text-files

I have a Socket program which is trying to write server data into text file present into the directory of the System.My program is working fine in Windows Operating System and i am able to get the data into the text file but when i am changing the directory name in Linux ubuntu i ma not able to get the data.Here is the structure if my directory in windows as well as in Linux..

```
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("D:\\Java\\Call.txt", true); //this is for windows and working fine
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/Call.txt", true);  For Linux Directory Path but its not working in Linux Ubuntu
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: maybe it's about permission issue.. try to write at your Document folder, it should have no problem..

Comment: It could also be a problem with spaces or other special characters in the path. Those would have to be escaped.

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 What directory name i should write instead of "/home/Call.txt"   for Ubuntu Linux

Comment: for example: `/home/my_user/Document/Call.txt`

Comment: You need to replace my_user with someone's user name.

Comment: Or you could use a relative path like "./Call.txt" to write it in the current working directory.

Comment: yea, @Paul is also correct, so the point is: you use `/` correctly to define the path, @Ram ..

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/home/vikas/Documents/Call.txt", true);  Is it OK.

Comment: yea, that seems OK to me.. does it still have any problem..?

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉 I will test and Update You ..

Comment: @YohanesKhosiawan许先汉  Yes sir its working fine.One more doubt if i have to save my text file into one of my Disks Just like D:/,E:/ In windows How to give names in that .My File System Name is "Anti-Virus"

Comment: On Linux block devices (e.g. hard drives, CDs, USB sticks,...) are mounted into the main file tree. Calling the command `mount` without any options will show you, where which device is mounted; it may be a place like `/media/Anti-Virus`.

Comment: @blalasaadri "Anti-Virus" i have under my "/Devices" so will my path name  "/Devices/Anti-Virus" will be correct

Comment: yea, @blalasaadri is correct.. and it may have more work actually, you have to make sure that your Windows partition (where you wanna read from) is already mounted.. i'm not remembering the details, you might wanna read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Comment: @Ram Not having an Ubuntu installation at hand, I can't be sure. But the easiest way for you to find out is to open a terminal, type `mount` and check the resulting output for your Anti-Virus device.